# Ubuntu wont detect my second monitor anymore

Tags: graphics, resolution, monitor

Is there a way to restart it to its default settings? i've tried everything else

> sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg

does not work

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the default opensource drivers or ati/nvidia drivers then one quick way to reset is simply to move to one-side xorg.conf and then reboot i.e.

```
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup
```

You rarely need to `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg` for the latest versions of Ubuntu.

### ATI Graphics

If you have been playing with ATI graphics installs then deactivate the driver from the Additional Drivers window and then reactivate to reinstall.

Additionally run the aticonfig routine to generate a new xorg.conf

```
aticonfig --initial -f
```

### NVIDIA

If you have been playing with NVIDIA graphics installs then deactivate the driver from the Additional Drivers window and then reactivate to reinstall.

You can also remove all references to nvidia kernels install via

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia*
```

Then reinstall the driver from Additional Drivers window.

Additionally run the Nvidia routine to generate a new xorg.conf

```
gksudo nvidia-settings
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your cables.

I know this is kind of a off-topic answer, but I spent hours blaming linux for the problem, upgrading and downgrading kernels, nvidia drivers, resetting X.

Turns out the years of linux being terrible with multi-monitor support has coloured my expectations, and once in awhile, a cable just stops working that reliably.